# Convert Element object to Int?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I came across phase in my code that I need to convert an `Element` object into `int` when I know  that the `Element` object holds an `int`. But I can't seem to find a way to convert that 
into an `int`. Here is the code:

```
       // extract data from XML file 
       NodeList roundNumber = element.getElementsByTagName("roundNumber");
       Element line = (Element) roundNumber.item(0);

       // now convert "line" into an int
```

How can I convert the `line` `Element` into an `int` ?

Comment: Do you mean the `roundNumber` element contains text that represents an integer?  If so, try calling `line.getTextContent()` and passing that to, say, `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: I don't do a lot with DOM `Element`s in Java, but perhaps you could use a combination of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779).

Comment: @RobI That your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Jim - I hesitate to make it an answer since it's essentially just a link to another SO question. The API link isn't, but I also don't have enough experience using `Element` to speak authoritatively on it. There may be a better API method or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(line.getTextContent());
```

Be sure that `line.getTextContext()` always returns an integer, or a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Comment: Just a comment, wrap this sentence in a try-catch block catching NumberFormatException just as a defensive programming tactic.

Comment: But the best practice is to validate the XML using a XSD before do something like that, or `line.getTextContent().matches("\\d+")` taking care with the size of number.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the name of the attribute you can do the following :

```
Integer.valueOf(line.getAttribute("<attribute name>"));
```